# Annoying drop shadow effect in iMovie

Tags: imovie

I've just started using iMovie 10.1.4 and I've been trying to get rid of this annoying drop shadow effect. I created a new title, chose 'centred', typed the text I want, and set it to a light grey colour. But whenever I go into video preview, or watch the final movie, it comes up with this drop shadow shown below.
[image: Christmas Design with Drop Shadow]
Is there any way to remove this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, this is the right place to ask this question.

Second, looking at iMovie, I think that the drop shadow is built into that particular title. Have you tried just using the "Standard" title and setting the font & color to the right one? It seems like that would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can mostly be due to the font and colour you are using. The font would be mostly the problem. Try changing these and see the result!